# Streaming directly to gulp.dest

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I’d like to make npm module which returns stream and then pipe it to `gulp.dest` in some other  app.

Example:

```
// some-module.js
module.exports = function() {
  return require('fs').createReadStream('someFile.txt');
}

// gulpfile.js
gulp.task('default', function() {
  var myModule = require('./some-module');
  myModule().pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Unfortunately for this code I got:

```
path.js:313
        throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.resolve must be strings');
              ^
TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
```

It works in this way

```
// gulpfile.js
gulp.task('default', function() {
  var myModule = require('./some-module');
  var fs       = require('fs');
  myModule().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('someOtherFile.txt');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [vinyl-source-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-source-stream) to convert your stream into a gulp-compatible stream.

Get it:

```
npm install vinyl-source-stream --save-dev
```

Usage:

```
// gulpfile.js
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  var myModule = require('./some-module');
  myModule()
    .pipe(source('someOtherFile.txt'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

The parameter to `source()` will be the filename used by `gulp.dest()`.